# Firebase wont work unless you update google play services

Tags: android, firebase, service, playback

Currently created a form that store user into Firebase server. However the app not responding due to an error named

> Firebase wont work unless you update google play services.

I have follow every step mentioned in the Firebase tutorial and yet it is still not working due to the google play services issue. May i know how to solve the google play services issue? The Firebase version is 15.0.0. Thanks

Comment: how about doing what it says and update google play services?

Comment: problem is 
1. I am not sure how to do it as the emulator does not act like phone having a google play store
2. I read from online there is a way of coding it but i either couldnt sync it or getting errors about version compatibility between firebase and android.

so im not so sure how to solve the problem based on online sources as some are really old to follow

Comment: There are emulator images that have the Play store on it.  You should be using those, as they will update Play.

Comment: based on android studio, API with google API should have the google play service but i downloaded the image and the error still there and the setting on emulator is missing a "Google play service" tab which my friend has it on default. Am i missing any line of code? or is there any useful sites that can answer my error?